# Annotation on Google Bar Chart

Tags: charts, annotations, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to add annotations to a bar chart but it doesn't work. When I use the package 'corechart' it works but I want to use the package 'bar'. This is my code :

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Hour');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'})

  data.addRows([
    [[00, 00], 200, 'one'],
    [[01, 00], 230, 'two'],
    [[02, 00], 400, 'three'],
  ]);
  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Hour',
      format: 'hh:mm',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Value'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#e3f2fd',
    legend: 'none',
    height: 450,
    width: 3000,
    colors: ['#00ACC1'],

    alwaysOutside: true,
    textStyle: {
    fontSize: 17,
    auraColor: 'none',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  } ,
  };
var chart = new
google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

}
```

Everything works perfectly, just the annotations are missing.
Thank you!

Comment: charts from package `'bar'` are considered _Material_ charts -- _Material_ charts do not support column roles, including annotations, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- for all of the unsupported options...

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat! I will use then something else. Have a nice day